# what are the minimum permissions required to restore a SQL Server database, add a user and grant it db_reader

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've got a Control-M process that takes a backup of s SQL database and restores it using SSIS.

I now need to add a db user and grant it db_reader access.  The user already has a sql authenticated login.

I have granted the Control-M dbcreator rights to restore the database but I can't think of any specific permissions I can grant to allow it to create the db user.  What's the best way to do this without granting sysadmin.

thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need any additional permissions beyond `dbcreator`.

When you restore the database, you should automatically have `db_owner` rights to that database.

`db_owner` will allow you to create a user and attach it to a pre-existing server login.

Comment: This is not quite true because I'm overwriting the existing database in which case it retains its original owner.  Which means that if I made the ETL user the owner of the original database then it should work as I want.  Thanks.